# Incorrect Points in Circumference

Tags: objective-c, math, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate points in a circumference and I do not get expected values.

I am calculating it like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) pointsForSegment:(int) segment
{
    NSLog(@"segment is %d", segment);
    NSMutableArray *points = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.numberOfPointsPerSegment; i++)
    {
        CGPoint point;

       double angle = self.angleIncrement * ((self.numberOfPointsPerSegment * segment) + i);
       NSLog(@"angle is %f", angle);

       point.x = self.radius * cos(angle);
       point.y = self.radius * sin(angle);

       NSLog(@"Point for segment is %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));

       [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
   }
   return points;
}
```

And I get the following log output:

```
// initial values
self.totalRenderCycles is 172
Circumference is 691.150384
Angle increment is 0.520871 
Number of points in segment is 4

// first 4 segments (16 point calculations)
segment is 0
angle is 0.000000
Point for segment is {110, 0}
angle is 0.520871
Point for segment is {95.4125, 54.7399}
angle is 1.041741
Point for segment is {55.5189, 94.9613}
angle is 1.562612
Point for segment is {0.900247, 109.996}

segment is 1
angle is 2.083483
Point for segment is {-53.9572, 95.8573}
angle is 2.604354
Point for segment is {-94.5037, 56.2943}
angle is 3.125224
Point for segment is {-109.985, 1.80043}
angle is 3.646095
Point for segment is {-96.2957, -53.1709}

segment is 2
angle is 4.166966
Point for segment is {-57.0658, -94.0399}
angle is 4.687837
Point for segment is {-2.7005, -109.967}
angle is 5.208707
Point for segment is {52.381, -96.7276}
angle is 5.729578
Point for segment is {93.5697, -57.8335}

segment is 3
angle is 6.250449
Point for segment is {109.941, -3.60039}
angle is 6.771319
Point for segment is {97.153, 51.5877}
angle is 7.292190
Point for segment is {58.5974, 93.0932}
angle is 7.813061
Point for segment is {4.50003, 109.908}
```

I have not applied these points to the circle centre yet to get the point on screen but I still do not see a logical progression through a circumference path in these logs.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have miscalculated your angle increment.

Remember that the end of each segment is also the start of the next segment. If I take the points you calculated and plot them in Excel, you can see how they wrap around after the third segment so that the final segment overwrites the first segment with a slight offset. Are you using degrees or radians?

[image: circle]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to plot them. :) I also asked this on the mathematics exchange and it was pointed out I mixed radians with degrees. I am using degrees. There seems to be the degrees/radians issue and a bounds issue. Im confused now :/ The numbers still look wrong to me. e.g. the 4th number (index 3 of segment 1) (0.9, 109) does not follow (55.5, 94.96)

Comment: Yes, I see those in segment 1 are starting at 3 o'clock and going back towards 12 o'clock. Make sure you calculate angle increment by dividing 90 degrees (or pi/2) by (point-in-segment + 1), then run some more data. Happy to plot more if you upvote me - lol ;-)

Comment: Thanks Roger. I need to calculate the angle beforehand. I am doing this - self.angleIncrement = 360.0 / self.circumference; should 360.0 be 90.0?

Comment: From what I understood, you have 4 segments, each 90 degrees, so if you want 4 points per segment you need an increment of (90 / 4) - sorry I said +1 earlier, wrong! - then you get points for the first segment at 0, 22.5, 45, 67.5 and for the second segment 90, 112.5, 135, 157.5 etc.

Comment: Oh no. I have 172 segments each with 4 indexes, totalling roughly the circumference of the circle. Each render cycle has 4 indexes. So I would like to calculate each point during increments. So 172 segments each with 4 indexes, and each index needs to have a point, based on a varying radius, and the angle increment.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood then, sorry, but the angle increment is independent of the circle radius (or circumference), it's only a function of the full 360 degree angle.

Comment: Yes, I cannot use atan as I dont have the points. What is the formula to get the angle increment? I guess this applies to calculating a sin wave phase value too.

Comment: If you want `n` points around the circle, then the angle increment is `360 / n` degrees.

Comment: Exactly, I did that. 360/circumference. I then get the issues I posted .

Comment: Ok but it should be in radians, so `(2 * pi) / circumference` objective-c sin/cos expects radians, no?

Comment: That seems to have done it as far as the logs look. Will render it tomorrow and see the result. Thanks for your time. :)